# Passing array of objects from EJS template to Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have a basic Node.js application and when a user hits a certain route, a number of records are retrieved from the database in the route and passed to my EJS template as an array.

This works fine, however, on the EJS template I have a button which calls a Javascript function to shuffle shuffle this array. How can I send this array as a parameter from the EJS template to the Javascript function? The usual <% %> does not seem to work in this scenario.

My code for passing the array to the template looks like this:

```
router.get("/home", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    Bean.find({ "userid": req.user._id }, function(err, beans) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {            
            res.render("home", { path: req.path, beans: beans }); 
        }
    });
});
```

In my template I can access the beans variable fine and loop through, however, I cannot pass it as a parameter like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow" role="button" onclick="match_engine(<% beans %>);">Match</a>
```

The above will give me an 'Expression Expected' error within my editor and the beans array will be undefined in my Javascript code. What am I doing wrong?

Furthermore, can I return this array from my Javascript file and use it as a new variable in my EJS?

Thanks in advance!

### EDIT:

On my EJS template I have the button as above and a table:

```
<table class="table table-striped"> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>Full Name</th> 
                    <th>Email</th> 
                    <th>Position</th> 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody>
                <% beans.forEach(function(bean) { %>
                    <tr> 
                        <td><%= bean.fname + " " + bean.lname %></td> 
                        <td><%= bean.username %></td> 
                        <td><%= bean.position %></td>
                    </tr> 
                <% }); %>
            </tbody> 
        </table>
```

My goal is for this table to be populated when the page is loaded (this works) and then when the user clicks the button, the beans array of objects is shuffled and re-displayed in the table.

Comment: Try `<%= beans %>` .

Comment: @Ofisora thanks, I did try that and I get an unexpected or invalid token error message. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to post the code of that `ejs` page?

Comment: @Ofisora I just posted the rest of my ejs page. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" you are trying to inject an object reference into a String that is going to be eval'd (`onclick="match_engine(...);"`). The important thing here is **reference**. I'd recommend you pass some kind of ID to the inline event handler and let `match_engine()` fetch the correct object by this ID from somewhere else.

Comment: What exactly is `match_engine()` supposed to do, and what data from `beans` is required to do that. Just realized that the markup is created on the server and then sent to the client. And the client has no reference whatsoever to the data. It might be possible to inject the respective data as JSON into the rendered markup.

Comment: @Thomas beans is an array of objects, each object has a name, email, age. What I want to do is pass this array of objects to some function (match_engine()), which randomly creates pairs of the objects in the array. I then want this to be returned to my ejs template and displayed in a table and stored back to the database. I hope that explanation helps?

Comment: @user2573690 if this would already require client-server communication, how about running `match_engine()` on the server and returning just the new markup? Or all the other way around. Running EJS on the client and just passing JSON back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

The `<% %>` stands for a javascript input that is not going to be shown in the HTML code, such as `<% for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ %>`, the `<%= %>` is used when you want this to be shown in HTML. In your case, it would be `<%= beans %>` instead of `<% beans %>`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve your goal by node.js unless your button call a function to reload the page or act like form submit button to reload or redirect the page with the required data.